# Need to apply edge filtering algorithm on series of images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

i wanna write a code in matlab which will accept images from an implicitly given directory and apply Sobel edge detection algorithm on each image on-the-go. Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobel edge detection in MATLAB only works on grayscale images so you would need to convert any images into a grayscale representation. If you have a folder on desktop where all the images reside, then the following snippet of code can do what you wanted.

```
dirname = '~/Desktop/imgs/';
files = dir([dirname, '*.png']);
files = {files.name}';
for ifile = 1:numel(files)
    imfile = [dirname, files{ifile}];
    im = imread(imfile);               % Read the image file
    img = rgb2gray(im);                % Convert to grayscale
    ime = edge(img, 'sobel');          % Edge detection

    figure(1)
    imshow(ime);
    outname = ['edge_', files{ifile}];
    imwrite(ime, outname);
end
```

Hope that helps.